# Learning big data for a real case

Tags: database, sqlite, bigdata

I made a database (150GB) to index the Bitcoin blockchain.

- table 1 : `id`, `block_height`, `block_hash` : 500 000 lines
- table 2 : `id`, `block_height`, `transaction_hash`  : 780 millions lines
- table 3 : `id`, `transaction_hash`, `address` : 480 millions lines

On a i7@3Ghz, 16GB RAM, Windows 10, SSD SATA3 I tried adding an index on `table3.address`. The RAM goes to 100% and after 30h there was an I/O error and the index was not created. I tried a `select distinct` on `table3.address`, after 86h of my SSD and RAM being at 100% I decided to kill the SQLite process.

What can I do? I'm going toward my custom solution : text files, one text file per address, per transactions, per block. Want to know all the unique address? List the files in the address folder. Want to know what happened in a transaction? Open the file with its hash.txt.

Comment: "I made a massive database (150GB)" - No, you didn't! 150 Terrabytes would be large, 1 Petabyte would be massive. 150GB is relatively small.

Comment: @sliders_alpha Are you adding the index before or after your insert?

Comment: @mypetlion after because I was told that inserting after creating an index would fragment it an render it useless